# How do you remove an element in an array list

Tags: c++, arraylist

I am reading in a list of elements into an array, then inserting an element, then deleting an element. I have gotten my code to insert an element fine. I have also gotten it to delete the element I want, but it will only output one element post the deletion.

```
void deletelist(listtype list[], int& numlist, int id, ofstream& outf)
{
    int i, where;
    where = 0;

    while (where < numlist && id > list[where].id) where++;

    if (list[where].id == id)
    {
        while (where < numlist - 1)
        {
            list[where] = list[where + 1];
            list[numlist] = list[numlist - 1];
            numlist--;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        outf << "The item doesn't appear to be in the list" << endl;
    }
}
```

I expect for the elements past the deleted element to move up 1 in the list. The next element after the deleted element does move up, but the rest of the elements after that do not output. I get no compiler errors.

Comment: I recommend learning how to use a debugger and using that to step through your code to see what's happening. That will be an invaluable skill in coding.

Comment: Could you explain what you think happens with each iteration of each `while` loop? (Not necessarily to us; explaining your code to a "rubber duck" is one trick for [how to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).)

Answer (score 0):

This has a bug:

```
while (where < numlist && id > list[where].id) where++;

if (list[where].id == id)
{
    …
```

If `where == numlist` at the end of the while loop (because the element specified by `id` wasn't found), then `list[where]` is an invalid position in the array and it's unsafe to inspect `list[where].id`.

Better:

```
while (where < numlist && id > list[where].id)
    where++;

if ((where < numlist) && (list[where].id == id))
{
```

But that's probably not your only bug.

You didn't say whether or not the array was definitively sorted.  Nor did you indicate whether `numlist` is supposed to be after the function returns.

My take is to assume the list is not sorted.  And that `numlist` should reflect the new size of the list.  In the case of removal, that would be `numlist = numlist - 1`.  Here's a simpler approach:

```
void deletelist(listtype list[], int& numlist, int id, ofstream& outf)
{
    int where = -1;

    // find the element
    for (int i = 0; i < numlist; i++)
    {
        if (id == list[i].id)
        {
            where = i;
            break;
        }
        else if (list[i].id > id)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (where != -1)
    {
        // shift all the elements after "where" over by 1 position to the left
        for (int j = where+1; j < numlist; j++)
        {
            list[j-1] = list[j];
        }

        // numlist reflects the new size of the list
        numlist -= 1;
    }
    else
    {
        outf << "The item doesn't appear to be in the list" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right. I forgot to mention that when reading in the list, the elements are being inserted one at a time. So as elements are inserted to the list, they are automatically sorted in the correct order by id. So sorting is not necessary.

Comment: There's no sorting in the above solution. However, I just made a quick change to break out of the initial `for` loop when `list[[i].id > id` becomes true.  The second `for` loop simply moves every item to the right of `where` one over to the left.  You are only removing at most one item from the list, so `numlist` only gets decremented by 1.